# Wiping all content under /Users but admin

Tags: script, apple-remote-desktop

We have hundreds of computers with LDAP setup and when students login their profiles remain for life. IS there an easy script or something that could be run to clean out the entire /Users directory all but select users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you're merely dumping the user data, you could use a bash script.  Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

for user in $( ls /Users ); do
 if [[ "$user" != "<someadmin>" || "$user" != "<someotheradmin>" ]]; then 
  rm -rf "/Users/$user"
 fi
done
```

For removing users from the local directory, you need to use `dscl`.  Check out [this SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/questions/180144/how-can-i-delete-a-mac-os-x-snow-leopard-user-account-from-command-line) for a launching pad on using dscl to remove an account from OS X's local directory.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a lab you may just want to reset them back to a disk image periodically. This way any changes including any saved files will be lost, but it would return the machine back to a predetermined state.

Comment: Normally I would agree with that statement, but from ARD the task can be done in a few minutes. Trying to image and setup almost 100 laptops to ethernet ports takes too much hands on time.

Comment: Is it OK to have these user's deleted daily? Is it possible to have the students use guest accounts? Could you dictate that the students connect the laptops to Ethernet port at a designated time?